# How can we run RUby script from Jenkins 2 Pipeline code

Tags: ruby, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can we execute ruby script in declerative pipeline code in Jenkins? Is it possible to write the script in Shared library and execute it from pipeline. Dont have the option to keep the file in Jenkins Server.

Comment: Had to include script as part of the git repository and use `sh 'ruby ./script.rb'`

Answer (score -1):

Had to include script as part of the git repository and use sh 'ruby ./script.rb'